# Blender-File to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es-2.0, blender

we want to make a 3D Game for Apple iPad and we ar thinking about
a possibility, to import 3D-Models from Blender into Xcode.

Is there a way to do that?

We want to use opengl-es 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode isn't a game engine or 3D SDK. You can't 'import' blender files into XCode. What you can do is take your 3D assets and use them within your apps, either directly through OpenGL (rather low level), or using a 3D engine such as Unity (easier).

Either way, there are a number of questions already on Stackoverflow that you might find useful:

[Opengl ES how to import a 3D model and map textures to it on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059584/opengl-es-how-to-import-a-3d-model-and-map-textures-to-it-on-runtime)

[Iphone + OpenGL ES + Blender Model: Rotation by Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280094/iphone-opengl-es-blender-model-rotation-by-touch)

[Choosing 3D Engine for iOS in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068018/choosing-3d-engine-for-ios-in-c)

...I highly recommend you take a look at what options are out there, decide on the best way to implement your 3D game (be it raw OpenGL or an engine), and go from there.